# Pass a form created with captured url parameters to a generic django view?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

This seems like it *should* be obvious, but the solution is eluding me. Normally I would just write a simple view function which would populate an appropriate form and pass it along to the view, but the solution feels so close ..

I have a form. I want to instantiate this form using an `object_id` that I've captured in the url, then send it through to my template using the `extra_context` parameter.

I have something like this:

```
class AddProductForm(forms.Form): 
    product = forms.IntegerField()
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
```

and this:

```
url(r'^products/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 
    'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',
    {'queryset': Product.objects.all(),
    'extra_context': {'form': AddProductForm({'product': <what?>, 'quantity': 1})},
    name='product_detail'),
```

Is there a way to replace `<what?>` above with the captured value of `object_id`? (Maybe a clever callable passed in `extra_context` could make the form for me?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that in your urlconf. Any callables you supply can not accept any arguments, so you won't be able to get the value of `?P<object_id>`.

You can however re-use the generic view in your own view to cut down on the amount of boilerplate you have to write:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_details
from your.forms import AddProductForm
from your.models import Product

def about_pages(request, object_id=None):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    f = AddProductForm({'product':object_id,'quantity':1})
    return object_details(request,queryset=qs,extra_context={'form':f},template='yourtemplate.html')
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is essentially what I did (ultimately I had to add extra fields to my form, so something like this was necessary anyway). I am left wondering what people use callables for in extra_context though.

Comment: See the generic views documentation on adding extra context - basically it is for additional querysets you may want to use in your templates.